# Estimating the parameters when only characteristic function is known

Tags: r, python, estimation, stochastic-processes, fitting

Recently I was working with a process named Variance Gamma with Stochastic Arrival (VGSA) and trying to fit this process on a given data.

To obtain VGSA, as explained in Carr et al. [2001], we take the VG process which is a homogeneous Lévy process and build in stochastic volatility by evaluating it at a continuous time change given by the integral of a Cox, Ingersoll, and Ross [1985] (CIR) process.
Formally we define the CIR process $y(t)$ as the solution to the stochastic differential equation,
$$
d y_t=\kappa\left(\eta-y_t\right) d t+\lambda \sqrt{y_t} d W_t
$$
where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion, $\eta$ is the long-term rate of time change, $\kappa$ is the rate of mean reversion, and $\lambda$ is the volatility of the time change.
The process $y(t)$ is the instantaneous rate of time change and so the time change is given by $Y(t)$ where
$$
Y(t)=\int_0^t y(u) d u
$$

The characteristic function for $Y(t)$ is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{i u Y(t)}\right) & =\phi(u, t, y(0), \kappa, \eta, \lambda) \\
& =A(t, u) e^{B(t, u) y(0)}
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
A(t, u) & =\frac{\exp \left(\frac{\kappa^2 \eta t}{\lambda^2}\right)}{\left(\cosh (\gamma t / 2)+\frac{\kappa}{\gamma} \sinh (\gamma t / 2)\right)^{2 \kappa \eta / \lambda^2}} \\
B(t, u) & =\frac{2 i u}{\kappa+\gamma \operatorname{coth}(\gamma t / 2)}
\end{aligned}
$$
with
$$
\gamma=\sqrt{\kappa^2-2 \lambda^2 i u}
$$

The stochastic volatility Lévy process, termed the VGSA process, is defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z(t) & =X_{V G}(Y(t) ; \sigma, \nu, \theta) \\
& =\theta \gamma(Y(t) ; 1, \nu)+\sigma W(\gamma(Y(t) ; 1, \nu))
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus $\sigma, \nu, \theta, \kappa, \eta$, and $\lambda$ are the six parameters defining the process. Its characteristic function is given by
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{i u Z_{V G S A}(t)}\right)=\phi\left(-i \Psi_{V G}(u), t, \frac{1}{\nu}, \kappa, \eta, \lambda\right)
$$
where $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $Y(t)$ given in (6.68)and $\Psi_{V G}$ is the log characteristic function of the variance gamma process at unit time, namely,
$$
\Psi_{V G}(u)=-\frac{1}{\nu} \log \left(1-i u \theta \nu+\sigma^2 \nu u^2 / 2\right)
$$

We define the stock process at time $t$ by the random variable
$$
S(t)=S(0) \frac{e^{(r-q) t+Z(t)}}{\mathbb{E}\left[e^{Z(t)}\right]}
$$

We note that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{Z(t)}\right]=\phi\left(-i \Psi_{V G}(-i), t, \frac{1}{\nu}, \kappa, \eta, \lambda\right)
$$
which is equivalent to $e^{-\omega t}$ in the VG case. Therefore the characteristic function of the $\log$ of the stock price at time $t$ is given by
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{i u \log S_t}\right]=\exp \left(i u\left(\log S_0+(r-q) t\right)\right) \times \frac{\phi\left(-i \Psi_{V G}(u), t, \frac{1}{\nu}, \kappa, \eta, \lambda\right)}{\phi\left(-i \Psi_{V G}(-i), t, \frac{1}{\nu}, \kappa, \eta, \lambda\right)^{i u}}
$$

For additional information, please refer to page 236 of the book titled "Computational Methods in Finance" by Ali Hirsa, specifically regarding the Variance-Gamma Stochastic Process (VGSA).

My approach involves initially inverse Fourier transforming the characteristic function and then utilizing the Log Likelihood method. Despite employing an initial guess and the Nelder–Mead method for minimization, the results obtained are often suboptimal, likely due to convergence to local minima.

I seek guidance on a more robust method to fit the VGSA model to my data for parameter estimation, as the current approach seems to be getting stuck at local minima. Any suggestions and code implementations in Python, R, or MATLAB would be highly appreciated.