# Estimating the parameters of a Process when only Charateristic function is known

Tags: r, distributions, python, estimation, fitting

<I asked a similar question earlier: [Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/639726/estimating-the-parameters-when-only-characteristic-function-is-known)>

I am seeking guidance on methods for estimating the parameters of a process when the characteristic function is known but the distribution is not. Theoretically, I understand that one can compute the moments of this process from the characteristic function. However, in my specific case, this computation proves to be challenging. Also, in my case, I needed to estimate 6 parameters, which became challenging when using the Log-likelihood method as most of the time the estimates kept being stuck on some local minima.

I am exploring alternative approaches to estimate the governing parameters utilizing the known characteristic function based on real data. I would greatly appreciate any insights or resources you could share on this topic, such as books, papers, or blogs.

Moreover, I am interested in practical implementations of these methods in Python, R, or MATLAB. If you could provide code snippets or information about relevant packages, it would be immensely helpful.

Comment: 1. If you know the likelihood function, you know the distribution.  2. You should be maximizing the log-likelihood, not minimizing it.  3. Multiple (local) optima are a real problem, sometimes, and there are approaches to help find good local optima, perhaps even the global optimum, such as simulated annealing.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you for your insightful comment. I'll look into simulated annealing further. I derived the likelihood function from the characteristic function through the process of taking the inverse Fourier transform. I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide guidance on implementing such a problem in Python or R, specifically when only the characteristic function is known, and the objective is to estimate the parameters. This guidance would be invaluable for someone like me who is relatively new to this field.